# I cannot get sftp get command to rename the file i am downloading

Tags: linux, unix, sftp

```
get file1.txt file2.txt
```

simply downloads `file1.txt` without any complaints.  It does not rename the file.  Nothing in the logs acknowledges the second parameter.  Whats going on?

SFTP version: `sftp: Tectia Client 6.3.11 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using would work with OpenSSH `sftp` (and other SFTP clients like WinSCP).

---

But Tectia `sftpg3` documentation *(no longer online)* does not indicate that it supports "target" filename parameter for the `get` command (nor any other way to rename the downloaded file):

> get [-p, --preserve-attributes] [-u, --unlink-source] [-I, --interactive] [--overwrite] [--checksum] [-W, --whole-file] [--checkpoint] [--streaming] [--force-lower-case] [--prefix] [--statistics] [--summary-display] [--summary-format] [--progress-display] [--progress-line-format] [--progress-line-interval] [--max-depth=] **file...**

---

Though, it has `sget` command that does what you want:

> sget [options...] srcfile [dstfile]